# VBA: .Offset function not working for Autofiltered range

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a dataset in which i wish to filter and delete all filtered rows based one a specified criteria.

The code I have below is working perfectly, except for the fact that it is also deleting the header row with each iteration. My hopes were that the .Offset(1,0) function would adress this, but so far no luck.

```
i = 0 'Variável de apoio (contador)
selecao = Array("GRUPO CARREFOUR - VAR", "GRUPO SONAE - VAR", "GRUPO WAL MART - VAR") 'Lista com os Clientes a serem filtrados
    
Do While i < 3:
    With Worksheets(pasta2).range("A1")
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=selecao(i)
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    
    Worksheets(pasta2).AutoFilterMode = False
    
    i = i + 1

Loop
```

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are filtering a one cell range.  There is no field #5.  You need to expand the range.

Comment: @DarrellH But the code works perfectly even with this range... The only problem is the header being deleted as well as the filtered data.

Comment: Find the last row on the sheet, then use `Resize` after offsetting to delimit the range that you're calling `SpecialCells` on.

Comment: @BigBen hm, could you show me how the code would look like applying this solution? Not sure I understood how to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the last row on the sheet, and then delimit the range you're calling `SpecialCells` on :

```
With Worksheets(pasta2)
    Dim lastRow as Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=selecao(i)

    On Error Resume Next '<~ ignore error if no visible cells
    .Range("A2:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: Also start with `.AutoFilterMode = False` (or better an `If` version) to get the correct filter (another could have already been applied).